# In Android, how to "DISABLE" bluetooth automatically when the battery level reaches a specific percentage?

Tags: batterylevel, battery-saver

Showing "unfortunately stopped" when running my application. I've got battery level percentage but turning off bluetooth is not working. Please help me out

NB: Its not a problem of permissions

if (bluetooth.isEnabled() && level<90) 
                    bluetooth.disable();

Comment: Might want to tell us what platform you're working on

Comment: oops!!! sorry..I'm working on Android.